# Bad 3d performance of intel ironlake

Tags: intel-graphics, performance

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 and got VERY bad 3d performance with intel ironlake comparing with a windows installation.

Is there any way I can improve this?

I already tried various paramaters of the i915 kernel module, but that didn't help much...
SNA is already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

### Add the following option in grub file

```
i915.semaphores=1
```

Then

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Mine is

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1  i915.semaphores=1"
```

### Try adding this to /etc/environment

```
 CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling
```

[[RESOLVED] Poor performance on Ironlake compared to old Intel GPU](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1058479)
[Intel Ironlake OpenGL Performance On Mesa 9.1](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMxMzA)

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the official graphics drivers for all intel processors. I had some minor problems with some games but this solved that issue.

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/

These drivers are given by Intel Open Source Technology Center and are always updated. Don't forget to add their source in your source list, to always get the updated drivers.